# Bison: If/Else reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm new in Bison. I'm getting reduce/reduce conflict error but not getting where it is happening .The error message is "conflicts: 1 reduce/reduce". This is my grammar rule .

```
%token INT FLOAT CHAR EXIT V_MAIN BS BE NL EQU CM ADD SUB MUL DIV LT GT LP RP PRINT IF ELSE THN HH
%token <VarNm> V_NM
%token <num> NUMBER
%token <flt> R_NUM
%type <num> EXP TERM FACTOR CON STATEMENTS 
%type <VarNm> X
%nonassoc THN
%nonassoc ELSE 
%start STRT
%left LT GT
%left PLUS MINUS
%left MULT DIV 

%%
STRT : V_MAIN BS CODE BE            {printf("Compilation complete. :)\n");}
    | EXIT                          {exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);}
    ;
CODE : /* empty */
    |   CODE STATEMENTS NL          {printf("Statements complete\n");}
    |   CODE DECLARATION NL         {printf("Declaration complete\n");} 
    |   STMNT 
    ;
DECLARATION :  TYPE V               {printf("D\n");}
    ;
TYPE : INT                          {printf("I\n");}
    | FLOAT                         {printf("F\n");}
    | CHAR
    ;
V : V CM V_NM                       {AddNewVar($3);printf("V\n");}              
    | V_NM                          {AddNewVar($1);printf("Vn %s\n",$1);}               
    | /* empty */                   {printf("E\n");}
    ;
STATEMENTS :                        { $$ = 0; }
    | EXP EQU X                     {AsgnVal($3,$1);}
    | PRINT EXP                     {printf("Output: %d\n",$2);}
    | EXP                           { $$ = $1 ;}                                                                
    ;
STMNT : MIF NL
    | UIF NL
    ;
MIF : IF CON THN HH MIF HH ELSE HH MIF HH   {printf("MIF1\n");}
    | CODE STATEMENTS NL
    ;
UIF : IF CON THN HH STMNT HH                {printf("UIF1\n");}
    | IF CON THN HH MIF HH ELSE HH UIF HH   {printf("UIF2\n");}
    ;
CON : EXP GT EXP                    { $$ =  $1 > $3? 1: 0 ; }
    | EXP LT EXP                    { $$ =  $1 < $3? 1: 0 ; }
    | EXP EQU EXP                   { $$ = $1 == $3? 1: 0 ; }
    ;
X : V_NM                            { $$=$1;CheckIfFound($1);}
    ;
EXP : TERM 
    | EXP ADD TERM                  { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | EXP SUB TERM                  { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    ;
TERM : TERM MUL FACTOR              { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | TERM DIV FACTOR               { if($3){$$ = $1 / $3;}
                                      else {printf("Division by zero\n");}   
                                    }
    | FACTOR                        { $$ = $1; }
    | X                             { $$=VarVal($1); }
    ;
FACTOR : NUMBER                     { $$ = $1; }
    | LP EXP RP                     { $$ = $2; }
    ;
```

The conflict error started when I inserted the grammar for IF/ELSE.
Excluding that portion my code works just fine . I would also like to know if there is any way to detect where is this conflict happening using command .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The problem is indeed triggered by your `if` productions. It goes like this (leaving out other irrelevant productions):

   ```
   MIF  : CODE STATEMENTS NL
   CODE : STMNT
        | CODE STATEMENTS NL
   STATEMENTS: %empty
   STMNT: MIF NL
   ```

   Note that `NL` is always a possible lookahead for `CODE` because `CODE: CODE STATEMENTS NL` and `STATEMENTS: %empty`, which means that `CODE` can derive `CODE NL`.)

   ```
   CODE NL⇒ CODE STATEMENTS NL NL     (CODE: CODE STATEMENTS NL)
          ⇒ STMNT STATEMENTS NL NL    (CODE: STMNT)
          ⇒ MIF NL STATEMENTS NL NL   (STMNT: MIF NL)
          ⇒ MIF NL STATEMENTS NL NL   (MIF: CODE STATEMENTS NL)
          ⇒ CODE STATEMENTS NL NL STATEMENTS NL NL
   ```

   That's certainly a reduce-reduce conflict. When the parser has found `CODE STATEMENTS NL` and sees `NL` as the lookahead, it could use either the reduction `CODE: CODE STATEMENTS NL` or `MIF: CODE STATEMENTS NL`.
2. If you were using the [Wikipedia dangling-else page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else#Avoiding_the_conflict_in_LR_parsers) as a guide (or even if you weren't), take a careful look at the production `closed_statement: non_if_statement`. (`closed_statement` is the equivalent of your `MIF`).
3. Although there is no magic command `where_is_my_error`, it's pretty easy to see that problem using the report file which bison will produce if requested (with the `-v` or `--report` options). See a fully worked out example in the [bison manual debugging chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Understanding). Also super-useful is bison's [trace facility](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing), which will save you from having to scatter `printf` statements throughout your parser (and later remove them).
4. Your grammar would be a lot more readable (to people other than you) if you conformed to the usual style guidelines:

   1. Use `UPPER_CASE` for tokens and `lower_case` or `camelCase` for non-terminals.
   2. Write words out in full. Rmvng vwls frm dntfrs mks yr cd nrdbl.
   3. Use bison's alias feature to write keywords as the keyword itself (in quotes):

      ```
      %token T_THEN "then" T_IF "if" T_ELSE "else"
      %%
      matchedIf: "if" condition "then" HH matchedIf HH "else" HH matchedIf HH
      ```

      See the [bison manual chapter on Symbols](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Symbols)
   4. You can also use single-quoted character tokens to simplify your grammar. These don't even need to be declared:

      ```
      term: term '*' factor
      factor: '(' expression ')'
      ```